# Web.Contents + Uri.EscapeDatastring = PARSER ERROR. PQ converts "%2F" to "/" but shouldn't

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

If I send a query to Google Webmaster Tool API (Search Console), it returns an error - 404 status.

**Here is a query**

https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/www.kvadroom.ru/urlCrawlErrorsSamples/obyavleniya%2Fprodaetsiya-taunhaus-sinkovskoe%2F201437169.html?platform=web&category=soft404&access_token=ya29.FgJLUjBKLvoQWXEJN6MsHPl4awqXr33uk8wIiCN_z4WWp4175JyrQeQRjmhGfIU6pMbF

(of course token has already expired, but was actual when used. Anyway, it's not a matter of credentials)

As you can see, a part of query string is escaped - it's a requirement of GWT API - https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/urlcrawlerrorssamples/get

If I paste query string to browser's adress bar, I get status Ok 200 with JSON response. But if I use the same query in PQ's Web.Contents, PQ parses string incorrectly - **it converts (but should not) "%2F" to "/"**

**It says**
[image]

Is it a bug or I do something wrong?

Suppose it happens only when escaped string is used in /path/ but not in ?params, i.e. precedes question mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is a (unwanted) feature of the URL library we are using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542(v=vs.110).aspx

We're currently not able to support this scenario.

For anybody frustrated by this, consider starting a topic at https://ideas.powerbi.com

---

Nice find!

I'm not able to find any workaround to get Power Query to make a request with "%2F" in the path.

Sorry about that. I'll add a bug to our team's backlog.

Comment: Not even double encoding? Seems the url get's URL-decoded before requesting it. Shouldn't `%252F` decode to `%2F` which will make the right request?

Comment: I tried "%252F" in Power Query, but funnily enough that is not decoded, and correctly requests "%252F". If you find a workaround please share, but I wouldn't try to make sense of the current behavior.

Comment: Some screenshots

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/puaT0.png

  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KrdkQ.png

  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HIjrB.png

Comment: So, @CarlWalsh, I don't understand if I can do something. Should I change some settings locally or I have to update Excel or .NET components? What and where should I change?